# Drive By Download Without User Interaction?

Tags: web-application, attacks, java, drive-by-download

Are there any kind of drive by download attacks (in Java maybe) that does not require any user interaction? When you make a drive by download in Java in general a popup appears to ask some permission to the user ([example of permission](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9k7Ev76cmP4/UU6SxVo7BHI/AAAAAAAACho/h-lyqi4Ie54/s1600/capturlcl.png)).

So is this attack exist without any user interaction process?

Comment: Yes - in Java maybe not so much these days, but there are many that exploit vulnerabilities in Adobe Flash, the browser, or the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many client side exploits on browsers (Internet Explorer, for example) and some plugins like Flash (and even some old Java ones I believe) do not acquire user interaction.